# Cascading drop down won't populate

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC5 and JQuery and I trying to create a cascading drop down. When the user selects a Practice from the drop down I am trying to get the Opticians that work in that Practice to populate.

Optician Model:

```
 public class Optician
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid OpticianId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserList { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Practice")]
    public Guid PracticeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Practice Practice { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PracticeList { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Practice> Practices { get; set; }
}
```

Practice Model:

```
public class Practice
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Practice")]
    public Guid PracticeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Practice Name")]
    public string PracticeName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Optician> Opticians { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

Application User Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult TestDropDown()
    {
        var PracticeListItems = (from d in db.Practices
                                 select d.PracticeName).ToList();

        SelectList Practice = new SelectList(PracticeListItems);
        ViewData["Practice"] = Practice;

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Opticians(Guid? Id)
    {
        var OpticianList = (from d in db.Opticans
                            where d.PracticeId == Id
                            select d.User.FirstName).ToList();

        return Json(OpticianList);
    }
```

The View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Optician").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Practice").change(function () {
        if ($("#Practice").val() != "Select") {
            var PracticeOptions = {};
            PracticeOptions.url = "/Bookings1/Opticians";
            PracticeOptions.type = "POST";
            PracticeOptions.data = JSON.stringify({ Practice: $("#Practice").val() });
            PracticeOptions.datatype = "json";
            PracticeOptions.contentType = "application/json";
            PracticeOptions.success = function (OpticianList) {
                $("#Optician").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < OpticianList.length; i++) {
                    $("#Optician").append("<option>" + StatesList[i] + "</option>");
                }
                $("#Optician").prop("disabled", false);
            };
            PracticeOptions.error = function () { alert("Error in getting Practices"); };
            $.ajax(PracticeOptions);
        }
        else {
            $("#Optician").empty();
            $("#Optician").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestDropDown", "Bookings1", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Select Practcie & Opticians</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Select Practice :", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Practice", ViewData["Practices"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Select Optician :", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select id="Optician"></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

However, when I run the application the Practice Name populates but the Optician First Name does not. There are no errors and I am unsure of where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: error is you loaded data into `ViewData["Practice"]` and in dropdownlist you gave 'ViewData["Practices"]'.

Comment: @JSantosh I changed that but the Optician drop down is still not populating

Comment: use `console.log(OpticianList)` in success callback and see what is the error in console.

Comment: Opticians action requires Guid Id, yet you are sending to it JSON.stringify({ Practice: $("#Practice").val() });

Comment: @ZoranP Sorry im very new to this, how do I pass the Id? I tried - stringify({Practice: $("#Practice").val(Id)});  but it did not work

Comment: { Id: $("#Practice").val() } - your property name was wrong, it should match the paramater name of the action

Comment: @ZoranP I changed it, but it is still not displaying the Opticians

Comment: ok your next error is that  $("#Optician").append("<option>" + StatesList[i] + "</option>"); should be  $("#Optician").append("<option>" + OpticianList[i] + "</option>");

Comment: @ZoranP I really appreciate your help, I'm afraid that doesnt work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88396/discussion-between-zoran-p-and-coto2).

Comment: You dont need ' PracticeOptions.data = JSON.stringify({ Practice: $("#Practice").val() });'   just use  `PracticeOptions.data = { Practice: $("#Practice").val() };`

Comment: @JamieD77 that returns an error unable to get Practices

Comment: @coto2  do one simple thing . just put a debugger at line `return Json(OpticianList);` and check what you are getting in `Id` and `OpticianList`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a few issues with your code.. Starting with your SelectList.

When you define your select list it helps if you tell it what your Value and Text properties are..

```
public ActionResult TestDropDown()
{
    var practices = new SelectList(db.Practices, "PracticeId", "PracticeName");
    ViewData["Practices"] = practices;
    return View();
}
```

Then you should probably return more information in your Opticians json result

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Opticians(Guid? Id)
{
    var opticianList = db.Opticians.Where(a => a.PracticeId == Id).Select(a => a.User).ToList();

    return Json(opticianList);
}
```

In your javascript once you get the names sorted out out you can reference the property FirstName of the result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Optician").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#Practice").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url = "@Url.Action("Opticians","Bookings1")",
            type = "POST",
            data = {Id : $(this).val() }
        }).done(function(OpticianList){
            $("#Optician").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < OpticianList.length; i++) {
                $("#Optician").append("<option>" + OpticianList[i].FirstName + "</option>");
            }
            $("#Optician").prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why you were passing paramater `Practice` to an action that took a parameter `Id` but it should be fixed in the code above.

Comment: Im afraid the Opticians is still not populating